# Scriptural reference for dead humans turning into Yamadūtas?

Tags: scripture, yama, supernatural-races

I heard that sometimes the dead can turn into Yamadūta. Is there any scriptural support for this belief?

https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/yamaduta